# Rank and count elements of list of lists in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

I have a `Genre` and a `User` models. Each `Genre` has an `id` and a `name`, and there is a many-to-many relationship, so that each `User` likes 0 or more `Genres`.

**Is there an efficient query for obtaining how many likes has each Genre, across all users, in descendant order?**

My current approach works, but it is extremely inefficient since it has to read all the likes of all the users for each genre:

```
In [1]: genres = list(Genre.objects.values('name', 'id'))

In[2]: genres
Out[2]: 
[{'id': 10, 'name': 'Rock'},
 {'id': 11, 'name': 'Pop'},
 {'id': 12, 'name': 'Hip hop'},
 {'id': 13, 'name': 'Electronic'},
 {'id': 14, 'name': 'Classical'}]

In [3]: likes_by_users = []

In [4]: users = list(User.objects.all())

In [5]: for u in users:
...:     current_user_likes = []
...:     likes_by_users.append(current_user_likes)
...:     for lg in u.liked_genres.all():
...:         current_user_likes.append(lg.pk)

In [6]: likes_by_users
Out[6]: 
[[14],
 [11, 12],
 [11, 10, 13, 12],
 [],
 [13, 12, 10, 1
 [10, 11]]

In [7]: counts = {}

In [8]: for g in genres:
    ...:     counts[g['id']] = {
    ...:         'name' : g['name'],
    ...:         'likes': 0
    ...:     }
    ...:     for l in likes_by_users:
    ...:         for gid in l:
    ...:             if gid == g['id']:
    ...:                 counts[gid]['likes'] += 1


In [9]: ranking = sorted(list(counts.values()), key=lambda x : x['likes'], reverse=True)
```

And this is exactly the output that I need:

```
In [9]: ranking
Out[9]: 
[{'likes': 4, 'name': 'Pop'},
 {'likes': 3, 'name': 'Rock'},
 {'likes': 3, 'name': 'Hip hop'},
 {'likes': 2, 'name': 'Electronic'},
 {'likes': 1, 'name': 'Classical'}]
```

Is there a query or another method for obtaining in an efficient way the required ranking?

Comment: This is an example from the docs: `Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2005).order_by('-pub_date', 'headline')` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ManyToMany fields in Django are backed by actual models (and thus tables).

You can get at the backing model via `.through`:

```
GenreLikes = User.liked_genres.through
```

For a simple many-to-many relation, the model will have two fields/columns, `user` and `genre` in in your case, one instance/row per user-like pair.

Thus, you should be able to get your ranking with just

```
GenreLikes.objects.values('genre').annotate(likes=Count('user')).order_by('-likes')
```

or similar.

Comment: Thanks. This approach worked, but I had to add `'user'` as a parameter for `Count()`. I would appreciate if you correct that, please.

Comment: @SusyP Done deal. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from django.db.models import Count
Genre.objects.annotate(likes=Count('user')).order_by('-likes')
```

Comment: `annotate` could be invoked directly on the `QuerySetManager` without chaining it to `all`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since this is a many-to-many relation, there is no `user` property, but a `liked_by` property. When calling `Genre.objects.all().annotate(likes=Count('liked_by'))` it just lists all the genres. When calling `Genre.objects.all().annotate(likes=Count('liked_by')).order_by('-likes')` it returns a huge list of genres with a lot of duplicate entries, so I think each entry represents a user's like of a genre. Is there a way to fix this query so that the result is similar to the `ranking` list from my question?

Comment: @SusyP Can you add your `User` (if it is not default) and `Genre` models to question?

Comment: @SusyP On my test app, my decision works fine without duplicate entries, not sure what is going wrong in your case.